# Can/Does Vortioxetine/Brintellix treat OCD?

Tags: medications, mental-health, antidepressants, obsessive-compulsive

According to Wikipedia, [antidepressants can treat OCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antidepressant), not just depression. Can/Does [Vortioxetine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vortioxetine)/Brintellix treat OCD? How? It doesn't say anything like that on Wikipedia.

Comment: Wikipedia's articles on drugs are very low quality on average. It's best to seek other sources when researching that.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't much literature on this, so my best guess might have to suffice.

OCD is on the anxiety spectrum of disorders. Vortioxetine is ineffective for GAD and therefore may not help remediate OCD symptoms.

**Edit**

Upon doing more research, I found evidence that both supports Vortioxetine as a treatment for GAD, and evidence that claims it is equivalent to placebo. Talk about confusing!

In regards to OCD, Reference 5 states that their evidence suggests newer "agents (ADs) should be tested more comprehensively.". It doesn't state that any of the newer antidepressants (which includes Vortioxetine) were ineffective. Based on Vortioxetine's mixed results for GAD, and the very vague and tentative for OCD, Vortioxetine is possibly an effective treatment for OCD.

**References**

1. (Against) A randomized, double-blind, fixed-dose study comparing the efficacy and tolerability of vortioxetine 2.5 and 10 mg in acute treatment of adults with generalized anxiety disorder., http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/24424707/?i=4&from=vortioxetine%20anxiety&sort=[relevance]
2. (Against) A randomised, double-blind, placebo-controlled, duloxetine-referenced study of the efficacy and tolerability of vortioxetine in the acute treatment of adults with generalised anxiety disorder, http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/24341301/?i=5&from=vortioxetine%20anxiety&sort=[relevance]
3. (For) Vortioxetine, a multimodal antidepressant for generalized anxiety disorder: a systematic review and meta-analysis., http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/25851751/?i=2&from=vortioxetine%20anxiety&sort=[relevance]
4. (For) Vortioxetine (Lu AA21004) in generalized anxiety disorder: results of an 8-week, multinational, randomized, double-blind, placebo-controlled clinical trial, http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/22898365/?i=14&from=vortioxetine%20anxiety&sort=[relevance]
5. An updated review of antidepressants with marked serotonergic effects in obsessive-compulsive disorder., http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/24766145/